# Submenu is behind main menu on hover

Tags: css, responsive-design, hover, z-index, submenu

I have [this](http://demo.themes-ck.com/index.php?option=com_content&templatename=vendolu&template=templatecreatorck&tmpl=preview) responsive Joomla template on [my site](http://kiskunhalasiszc.hu/) and I can't able to set dropdown submenu. It's always behind main menu and also behind the slider. I've already tried z-index and relative position, but still not working. Does anybody know why or what did I miss?

html

```
<div id="nav">
<div class="inner clearfix">
    <ul class="nav menu">
        <li class="item-101 current active">Main menu 1</li>
        <li class="item-112">Main menu 2</li>
        <li class="item-147 deeper parent">Main menu 3</li>
            <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
                <li class="item-151">Submenu 1</li>
                <li class="item-152">Submenu 2</li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include enough code in the question to reproduce the error.

Comment: Please provide a `JsFiddle` / the css that governs those elements so we can have a full picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your nav:

```
#nav {
    z-index: 10000;
    position: relative;
}
```

The `z-index` will push it above the body element, the `position: relative` is needed for the z-index to take effect.

Comment: Wow. Thanks! You saved my life.

Comment: I added those styles using the chrome inspector and it worked. Maybe it wasn't selected clearly enough in the css?

Comment: ok, you helped the guy. Here goes my +1 for you. (: